# What do the symbols next to car stats mean?

Tags: grand-prix-story

As far as I can tell, these symbols are never explained in the help menu. They seem to be indicators of quality (listed from best to worse, based on my experience):

- Concentric circles
- Circle
- Triangle
- X

Are these all of the possible symbols? Do they have precise meanings, or are they only vaguely representative of the attribute's quality?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already worked out the order of quality, these just seem to be a quick measure of how good the car is in a particular mode.

For On-Road, Off-Road and Icy Road you can get a better picture by - when starting a race - going to the change vehicle screen to select a car to race. At the bottom of this page, under the car parts, is a "Road Effect" score give as a positive or negative percentage (presumably a performance modifier of sorts)

My rough experience so far is:

- Concentric circles - positive bonus.
- Circle - no bonus.
- Triangle - slight negative bonus.
- X - large negative bonus.

Unfortunately this doesn't help a great deal for the Adv or Rep scores, which I cannot find a better measure for and we can only assume the same rough measures.